# code in not called function cause MPI program failed when cross nodes

Tags: mpi, trace, slurm, openmpi

I am using [mpiP](https://github.com/LLNL/mpiP) to trace MPI program, and make some modifications to mpiP. I want to record MPI function parameter information, so I create a buffer.
I add a list_t struct below in mpiPi.h:

```c
typedef struct
{
  int size;
  int capacity;
  char *data;
} list_t;
```

I also add some function calls for this struct in mpiPi.c (but not called yet):

```
void list_init(list_t *list)
{
  list->size = 0;
  list->capacity = 65536;
  list->data = (char*)malloc(list->capacity*sizeof(char));
  if(list->data == NULL)
  {
    printf("error: insufficient memory for initializing list\n");
  }
}
void list_finalize(list_t *list)
{
  free(list->data);
}
void list_push(list_t *list, char *item)
{
  if (list == NULL) return;
  int item_size;
  item_size = strlen(item);
  if(list->size + item_size >= list->capacity) {
     list->capacity = list->capacity*2;
     list->data = (char*)realloc(list->data, list->capacity*sizeof(char));
  }
  if(list->data == NULL) {
    printf("error: insufficient memory for pushing an item\n");
  }
   else {
   strcpy(&list->data[list->size], item);
   list->size = list->size + item_size;
  }
}
```

After add all this code above, I found that all MPI program failed with my modified mpiP when across nodes, but it worked when using single node. After I comment out some line of list_push, it then can work properly. The failure is like below, and no more infomation is provided from my slurm error log.

```
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
```

The lines which after I comment out make the MPI program work are:

```
    list->data = (char*)realloc(list->data, list->capacity*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&list->data[list->size], item);
    list->size = list->size + item_size;
```

I am confused that I just decalre this function and never call it, why do the three lines make this error? How can I avoid this problem?

MPI version: 3.1.0

gcc version: 4.8.5

Linux uname: Linux sh3login06 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I make a combination of which line cause this problem, and I found there are 3 lines causing this problem in list_push.

```
    list->data = (char*)realloc(list->data, list->capacity*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&list->data[list->size], item);
    list->size = list->size + item_size;
```

Comment: are you sure these subroutines are not defined by other libraries? what if you declare them `static` and/or prefix them with something unique?

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I use grep to search all the file in the dir, and there is only one result. There is no warning and mistake during compilation of mpiP. I try to use `static`, which helps. But I still dont know why this problem happened in multiple nodes and in contrast everything works fine in a single node.

Comment: remove `static`, use a debugger, set a breakpoint in `list_push` and see who calls it besides your program.